# Take values from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a problem about getting a value from my `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

My code is:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myArrayList;
```

and then:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put(TAG_ID, id);
map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
myArrayList.add(map);
```

If I want to get the name, for example, I tried as follow but I obtain a runtime error (the application crashes):

```
System.out.println(myArrayList.get(1).get(TAG_NAME));
```

How can I solve it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Never forget to include the complete error messages you get. It contains the necessary information to fix the error...

Comment: Do you initialise myArrayList anywhere? `myArrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

Answer (score 6):

`System.out.println(myArrayList.get(1).get(TAG_NAME));`

`ArrayList` is 0-based. `get(0)` instead.

Comment: I've already tried as you say, but the array list is populated by 64 hash map and the problem persists

Comment: @kareth perhaps post your error message along with some more information, or really it is hard to tell.

Comment: what do you mean by 64 has map ? size of the arraylist ?

Comment: Exactly, I'm sorry for my unclear problem description. I fill my ArrayList with (key,value), and its size is 64. The problem now is to take a field (for example "name") from my HashMap inside ArrayList. If I want to take a String (eg the "name" of the 4th HashMap inside the ArrayList) how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the list like this

```
   for(Map<String, String> map : myArrayList)
    {
        String tagName = map.get(TAG_NAME);
        System.out.println(tagNAme);
    }
```